# Proper method to attach horizontal board to beam posts in outdoor patio?

Tags: outdoor, patio, television

I want to mount a TV using a basic TV mount. I do not want to mount onto the exterior wall and the back roof truss does not have a joist hanger so I can't use a side-facing TV mounting plate.

The two blue posts bear the load of my roof and are 4x6 (4x5.5). What is the proper method to attach a horizontal board so I can then mount a TV mount to it?

I was thinking of using a 2x10 (so when I mount the TV mount the bolts are at least 2" from the top and bottom edges) and attaching them to the inside-facing faces using joist hangers. I'd likely use 10D nails to connect joist hanger to beams and 10d 1.5" nails where the hanger connects to the horizontal board. Any ideas or thoughts are much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: So you'd put a joist hanger on each of the black 4x6 posts and mount the 2x10 across the window, supported at each end?

Comment: What's the span between the two posts?

Comment: Have you thought about a screen and a projector instead of a TV? How big (and heavy) is the TV. You might be able to suspend it on wires/cables or a high cross beam to keep it looking a little cleaner.

Comment: Thanks all. @brhans, yes, I am thinking to put a joist hanger on each of the posts and mount a 2x10 across the window. It will not touch the window and that window never opens so I don't mind.

Comment: @mmathis The span is between 7 and 8 feet between the two posts.

Comment: I would consider adding a strongback to reinforce your cross member. I have a sneaking suspicion that either your TV or the mount might not take kindly to the amount of flex you'll get if the screen catches the wind. You don't need to over-engineer things, but you do need to keep in mind that a flat screen is a relatively large surface and allow for a bit of flex or stiffen things up.

Comment: @MatthewGauthier I've been Googling what a strongback is and if I understand correctly is it just a second 2x butting up behind the proposed horizontal 2x I plan on installing to prevent sway and twist? I hadn't thought about the effect of wind against a TV hanging from the 2x10. I may be more conflicted about whether to even proceed with trying to mount at TV.

Comment: A strongback is anything to prevent flex: boards attached to the back making a T or U shape, or a length of angle iron. (A less bouncy TV is probably more pleasant viewing.) Alternately, depending on the mount itself you may want to put a short piece of 2x10 as a mounting block to move the TV away from the plank, making the ends of the screen less likely to impact if the board flexes. -- One option is a piece of angle iron from a local scrap yard. You can cut off two short pieces to use as mounting brackets for the plank and the remainder as reinforcement.

Comment: BTW, the wind load should be relatively modest so it doesn't spell disaster. My original points were simply that you shouldn't plan on the board remaining completely rigid and should be careful about mounting the TV flush. Second that a TV flapping back and forth even fractions of an inch is a less than ideal viewing experience and probably worth addressing while you can do so easily.

Comment: @MatthewGauthier Okay, thanks for helping clarify what it is and how to do it. I am still brain-storming and hope to do something this weekend. I'll update if I have questions and once complete will show the final result. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your 2x10 idea is just fine. I wouldn't use hangers, though. They'll be ugly.

I'd do this:

1. Cut a 2x10 beam to length, fitting it between the posts.
2. Mount pairs of [slotted bed rail brackets](https://www.google.com/search?q=slot%20hangers&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS738US738&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI3MjQ-oHVAhUM32MKHfg5DAcQ_AUICygC&biw=1222&bih=633#tbm=isch&q=slotted%20bed%20rail%20bracket) to the back side of the board, flush with the ends, one high and one low.
3. Set heavy screws as appropriate to engage the slotted brackets.
4. Paint the board and hang it.

Either that or simply mount it to the outer faces of the posts with nice screws. If you fit it well, that would look fine. It really depends on how deep you want the tv to be.

Comment: In order for both sides to be inserted I'd have to have some wiggle room to "pull" one post outward in order for the bracket's "teeth" to be placed into the receiving bracket. Unless they make flush-mount side-insertion bed rail brackets. ??

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting. [Here's an example.](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51y0AFOjzWL._AC_UL320_SR226,320_.jpg)

Comment: Oh okay. And would you recommend using 10D nails (3") into the beams or deck screw? What fasteners into the 2x10? I'm overly worried about shear strength (mount + TV is around 60 lbs.).

Comment: No nails. Screws in the 3" range. The head style is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the span is more than 10 ft you might think about making something like a nice looking header beam by sandwiching OSB between 2 2x8's or 2X10's this will give you a lot more strength and be less wobbly.  If you do go with the standard galvanized beam hangers you first mentioned you should use galvanized 'Tico' nails, not your common 10D sinker.

Otherwise to look the best, and spend more $$, you could get a GluLam beam and use decorative exposed bolt brackets to attach to your verticals.

Just some brainstorms for you.